# Passing String between 2 Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

from Data Class I get a string and trying to pass it to the OpenedClass but when I click the button nothing actually happens. since Debugger doesnt show the error .I assume my activity doesnt work but I have no clue why ?

here is my Data class

```java
package com.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Data extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button start, startFor;
    EditText sendET;
    TextView gotAnswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSA);
        startFor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSAFR);
        sendET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSend);
        gotAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGOT);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        startFor.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bSA:
            String bread = sendET.getText().toString();
            Bundle basket = new Bundle();
            basket.putString("key", bread);
            Intent a = new Intent(Data.this, OpenedClass.class);
            a.putExtras(basket);
            startActivity(a);
            break;

        case R.id.bSAFR:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and here my code related part of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".Data"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Data" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OpenedClass"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="OpenedClass" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting into the expected `case` of the `switch`?

Comment: @UrielFrankel what exactly you wanna see in logcat ?

Comment: Did you properly add the button's listener? Can you show us more of the code where you added the listener

Comment: @Rodrane : it simply mean `onClick` event not firing so just add more code from Data Activity

Comment: @rasen58 added listener part.

Comment: Add log message in the `case` of the `switch` and make sure it is logged. Then we will know where the configuration breaks.

Comment: just posted whole Data.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not calling `initialize()`  in `onCreate` of Activity so call it after  `setContentView` as:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);

        initialize() ;  //<<< call initialize method here
    }
```